# Best way to write C ++/CLI nested object accessors

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli, clr, wrapper

Here is the situation:

I have an Unmanaged library Written in C/C++ and I would like to access those functions and structures in the CLR, but I am having trouble with writing basic accessors for the nested objects.  Here is an example of how these structs are laid out in those libraries:

```
struct MyObjectUnmanaged
{
    SurfaceUnmanaged s;
    ...
}

struct SurfaceUnmanaged
{
   int numPoints;
   double *gridz;
   ....
}
```

MyObjectUnmanaged has multiple structures nested within, and even structs like SurfaceUnmanaged will also have nested objects.  The user also needs to be able to allocate memory into these structures.

In the unmanaged library, The user creates an instance of MyObjectUnmanaged and modifies each of the necessary members by hand.  The user also accesses members of any nested objects and sets those values as well.  Finally, the pointer to the instance of MyObjectUnmanaged is passed into a static function where it is again modified.

Here is my managed wrapper for MyObjectUnmanaged

```
public ref class MyObjectWrapperManaged  
{
    private:
    MyObjectUnmanaged *o

    public:
    MyObjectWrapperManaged(){ o  = new MyObjectUnmanaged();}

// How should I write the accessors,properties
// or functions to modify objects nested within o?

   void SetNumPointsForSurface(int numPts); // accessors like this seem inefficient and 
                                            // gratiutous especially if there 
                                            // are a lot of members to access and modify

}
```

Should I be creating Managed wrappers for SurfaceUnmanaged? If so, would they be public members of MyObjectWrapperManaged or would properties and accessors just return new instances of the hypothetical SurfaceManaged class? What is the best way a client could access SurfaceUnmanaged to allocate memory from the top Level?

Comment: I'd say you're doing it right, inefficient and gratuitous is about par for the course.

Comment: I was afraid someone was going to say this... So would you recommend having public members of SurfaceManaged in the Wrapper in the last code segment or what? How would you "bind" them to the unmanaged object's respective members?

Comment: @GCar89: It's perfectly feasible to have a single function that accepts a .NET collection and both sets the size of the native surface object and also fills in its content.  It really depends on what interface you want to expose to .NET.